# Python3 - variable deceleration

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've started learning Python, and I would like to practice it by solving Leetcode problems.
I choose this one to start with: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

In the editor I have chosen Python3 which gives the following starting code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

I have copied this code to Visual Studio Code, and completed it with some commands, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'List' is not defined
  File "F:\Development\TestConsolePy\solution.py", line 2, in Solution
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
  File "F:\Development\TestConsolePy\solution.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Solution:
```

I have Python 3.8.5 installed on my Windows machine.

From what I have seen online usually python does not have type declarations - but in my case I figured I must be missing something as I choose python3 and running python3 on my machine... (If I take the same command and paste them into the python code generated by Leetcode than it works).

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `from typing import List`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Just to be clear, Python has *type hints* in later version (3.6+ I believe). It's dumb though that Leetcode auto-populated code that requires imports, then doesn't include the imports.

Comment: I don't know why you get type hints and annotations as a starting point. It's definitely nothing one needs when starting to learn python. Just use `def twoSum(self, num_list, target_num):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from typing import List` should solve your problem.

This module also contains other objects for annotating functions signatures like which you may want to import to make potential other code work

Comment: Why is it not needed to import if I don't put the type? What's the use of it? I see that I can do `my_list = list()` to create a new list - so why would I need the `List` at all?

Comment: These are two different things. list is a builtin type used to create lists, List is an object which is used to describe, what kind of datatype an argument should be. List[float] e.g. means, your argument should be a list of floats only. Other datatypes like dict also have a pendant (here Dict).
These type annotations are mainly used in conjunction with static type checkers like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)

Comment: So basically it's python's way to add typed declarations? Is it for compiler only or is it really enforced to have gains instead of variables that can be of any type?

Comment: Yes, its python way for typed variables. However thy are NOT enforced by the compiler (yet), but they a) can be accessed programmatically and so you could write functions which check types for essential functions or b) can be used in conjunction with external type checkers. You don't get any speed improvements with these afaik